# SwiftData/ModelContainer.swift:144: Fatal error: failed to find a currently active container for Student

Tags: ios, swiftui

I am currently following the tutorial from [Hacking with swift](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/introduction-to-swiftdata-and-swiftui) to integrate SwiftData into a SwiftUI project. The code generated based on the tutorial is provided below. However, an error occurs upon launching the app: `SwiftData/ModelContainer.swift:144: Fatal error: failed to find a currently active container for Student`.

I am seeking assistance in resolving this issue.

```swift
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

@Model
class Student {
  var id: UUID
  var name: String

  init(id: UUID, name: String) {
    self.id = id
    self.name = name
  }
}

@main
struct project8App: App {
  
  var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
      VStack {
        ContentView()
      }
    }
    .modelContainer(for: Student.self)
  }
}

struct ContentView: View {
  @Environment(\.modelContext) var modelContext
  @Query var students: [Student]
  
  let allStudents = [
    Student(id: UUID(), name: "John"),
    Student(id: UUID(), name: "Paul"),
    Student(id: UUID(), name: "George"),
    Student(id: UUID(), name: "Ringo"),
  ]
  
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      ForEach(students) { student in
        Text("\(student.name)")
      }
      Button(action: {
        // random student
        let student = allStudents.randomElement()!
        modelContext.insert(student)
      }) {
        Text("Add/Change name")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

P.S. It appears that the problem may be related to the container not being initialized by `.modelContainer(for: Student.self)`. I have managed to resolve the error with the modified version below. However, I am still curious about the reasons behind the original version's malfunction and the differences between the two implementations.

```swift
// version 2, which is ok to run

@main
struct project8App: App {
  let modelContainer: ModelContainer
  init() {
    do {
      modelContainer = try ModelContainer(for: Student.self)
    } catch {
      fatalError("Could not initialize ModelContainer")
    }
  }
  
  var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
      VStack {
        ContentView()
      }
    }
    .modelContainer(modelContainer)
  }
}
```

Comment: I think it is SwiftData bug, since it's quite new. According to the documentation, they said `Sets the model container in this scene for storing the provided model type, creating a new container if necessary`. However, on the stack trace when it crashes, it's because of Fatal error when failing to find a currently active container. Seem likes the container was used before its initialization. I guess you have to workaround with this.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem**

When app launched with code scenario 1 .

These steps are taken.

App > contentview > ContentView.init > Student init >
PersistentModel.createBackingData.

You see first content view init is called. Your students array is the property of content view which gets initialized with in Content view's init.

It tries to create student model which persistable model but container is not ready yet which is needed to create backing data.

Container is created lazily and a closure is called when its ready

```
 .modelContainer(for: Student.self) { result in
            debugPrint("data container ready")
        }
```

You can add print state to init of content view.

```
        debugPrint("Content view init called")
   }
```

If you run it you would find that Content view's init is called before container is ready.
Hence you get the crash.

**Solution**

Move students arrays to outside of Content view class or in some internal function so Content view' init can be called without the need of creating student model which needs container and its not ready yet.

```
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

@Model
class Student {
    var id: UUID
    var name: String
    
    init(id: UUID, name: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
    }
}

@main
struct project8App: App {
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            VStack {
                ContentView()
            }
        }
        .modelContainer(for: Student.self)
    }
}

let allStudents = [
    Student(id: UUID(), name: "John"),
    Student(id: UUID(), name: "Paul"),
    Student(id: UUID(), name: "George"),
    Student(id: UUID(), name: "Ringo"),
]

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) var modelContext
    @Query var students: [Student]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(students) { student in
                Text("\(student.name)")
            }
            Button(action: {
                // random student
                let student = allStudents.randomElement()!
                modelContext.insert(student)
            }) {
                Text("Add/Change name")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In code scenario 2 you are creating container before its being used hence no crash.

Comment: This answer is correct.  The basic idea is that you cannot initialize a Student before the container is ready.  In the original tutorial they are not hard coding an array of students like you are -- it is done the moment the add button is pressed.  You are just doing this for testing purposes and in a real app you wouldn't do this, so there is not really a big problem.  I would not suggest altering the initialization process but instead change your approach... just make the the hardcoded array an array of names and initialize the Student instances later.

Answer (score -1):

The other person's explanation basically says that the app crashed because things were happening in the wrong order. By moving the student array setup outside of the ContentView struct, they made sure that ContentView gets ready before trying to create the student model. This simple change avoided the crash caused by the container not being ready on time.

Yeah, that solution was smart. By separating the student array setup from ContentView's initialization, they prevented ContentView from jumping the gun and trying to access the model before it was good to go. It's all about getting the timing right to keep things running smoothly.

Timing is everything, especially when it comes to setting up data models and containers. Making sure things happen in the right order can save you from those pesky runtime errors. The revised code in scenario 2 shows a more careful approach to handling the initialization process, avoiding the crash that happened before.

Comment: I think you may have a down-vote because this is more of a comment and not a solution. IMHO there's nothing wrong with what you've said but it doesn't have code to illustrate how you would tackle the problem. Check out SO's tips: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer